# Chinese characters in URL can not be get

Tags: java, forms, jsp, utf-8, cjk

I have this url: `http://localhost:8080/Test/jsp/index.jsp?userName=%E5%AE%98%E8%AF%9D`. But when I tried to get the `userName`:

```
<meta http-equiv="test" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <%
    String username = request.getParameter("userName");
    out.print("<b>"+username+"</b>");    
  %>
```

The `userName` printed is unreadable. My page is already UTF-8 and it is also saved as UTF-8, how do I get and print the exact Chinese characters?

Comment: what was are you using?  You probably need to set the uriencoding to utf-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should encode your URL (this is Python, use the equivalent Java method):

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'userName':'官话'})
'userName=%E5%AE%98%E8%AF%9D'
```